# If a teenager runs away illegally but turns 18 before being found, are they still in danger?

Tags: united-states, minor

Could the police still take them back home against their will or otherwise prosecute them?

Comment: What does "in danger" mean?  What state?

Comment: Can you give an example of a run away being punished for running away? Most states have statutes that make running away a crime, but it is very rarely prosecuted. More often harboring a runaway is punished more often than the runaway themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Once the search goes out...

Once the police get the report of a missing person and they actually do *file* it (which can be tricky if the person is in the 18-21 gap but much easier below 18), the missing person is in their system. Contrary to popular belief, there is no 24 hour waiting period to report a minor missing, that is a rule that only regards adults and is not universal for all agencies.

Once the file is in the system, the report is reported upwards, because the states are forced to report any missing people under 21 to the NCIC under the Crime Control Act of 1990 - [42 U.S.C § 5779a](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/5779) (transferred to [34 U.S.C § 41307](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/34/41307)). This means, even if they are 18 now, the initial report to the NCIC still went up, possibly back when it was initially reported, maybe even still if the report happens after the 18th birthday. And they are still a *missing child* in the eyes of the NCIC.

> (a)In general
>
> Each Federal, State, and local law enforcement agency shall report each case of a missing child **under the age of 21** reported to such agency to the National Crime Information Center of the Department of Justice.

The entry in the NCIC database however will remain even long after the 21st birthday, as it can only be removed  by the [initial reporting agency](http://www.psp.pa.gov/law-enforcement-services/Documents/Clean%20Documents/CLEAN-NCIC-Group_Filing_Procedures.rtf):

> Missing Person: Adult and Juvenile: Retained until cancelled[sic!] by entering agency.

The database for missing children is for example used by [missingkids.org](https://www.missingkids.org/search) and can be searched. Using a search for people disappeared before their 18th birthday and now aged above 50 resulted in 373 cases [+ the test-file] that are listed there. The oldest in that sample is [Melvin Horst](https://www.missingkids.org/poster/NCMC/1311686/1/screen), who disappeared in 1928 and would be 96 by now. And yet, his entry is still online and can only be removed by the originally reporting agency. At the same time, more than 500 cases are people that disappeared below 18 and are now 18-21, about 400 of which disappeared between their 16th and 18th birthday.

A similar database is [the Charley Project](http://charleyproject.org/case-searches/chronological-cases), which sources from the same database and the initial reports - and their list has more than 13000 cases. It's not separated between kids and adults. They too list [Melvin Horst](http://charleyproject.org/case/melvin-charles-horst), their 7th oldest case, their youngest case is from fall 2019 as they only list cases older than a year due to practical limitations.

## Once apprehended

How each state handles **found** children or young adults that are reported missing is dependant on the state. Often, the act of the child running away on the own volition (or the report the child gives to police once apprehended) will trigger an inquiry by the CPS (or equivalent) into the living situation and could mandate foster care for some time or give some reasons for full emancipation - however that would be very dependant on the individual case.

Comment: What does it mean for a person between 18-21 to be "missing"? With a child, I can imagine some definition along the lines of "not being where the custodial parent told them to be", but for an adult, they are free to go wherever they want.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's why it is tricky to report them missing. Missingkids currently has currently 218 missing people that have been reported missing while they were between 18-21 (and now might have any age), 45 of them still are in that age bracket. As I write this on September 10th, the most recent such report is from September 2nd of the year. It's basically your ability to convince the police that they might be endangered or that they would have called back by now or that they have not returned to their home, or if there is some evidence to why they might not have returned.

Comment: @Acccumulation A person 18-21 could still be missing, just as adults can be missing. Often someone who is missing for a prolonged period of time is actually dead or has been abducted. Less often someone might have amnesia and not know who they are. They wouldn't be a runaway. But they could still be missing.

Comment: @ohwilleke I was contrasting 18-21 to below 18, not to above 21. My question also applies to people above 21: what definition is being used for "missing"? Sure, I can imagine why someone might think of an adult as "missing", but what *legal* definition is there?

Comment: "A missing person [who is not a child] is a person 18 years old or older whose disappearance is possibly not voluntary" https://definitions.uslegal.com/m/missing-person/

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes running away is a juvenile offense, but it is not an offense for which an adult aged eighteen or over would be arrested or punished. An adult would not be returned home.

Comment: So someone under 18 could be punished by the legal system for running away?

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes. Running away is a juvenile offense. At a minimum the runaway would be returned to parents, but the juvenile could also be prosecuted.

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly disturbing. What, children are property of their parents? Surely a large proportion, if not the majority, of children who run away do so because of abuse.

Comment: @Acccumulation If the juvenile justice system thinks you've run away because you are a "bad kid" (something especially common in the case of foster kids and kids adopted at older ages from the foster care system, and kids with a history of disciplinary issues or juvenile justice violations), it will often punish the kid.